# Old Motobecane pedals without bolt on axle - How to remove?

Tags: repair, pedals, vintage, rust, restoration

I took off some old pedals from a motobecane frame. I wanted to change the bearings but figured out there is no bolt. I have looked everywhere but can't find the model and how to remove it. I thought that it might need a special tool otherwise it might not be serviceable.

Does someone know how to remove this?

[image: Side view of the pedal]

[image: pedal]

[image: pedal]

Comment: There's a cap missing on the outer side that should have reduced water ingress. For the rest, greased 'for life' and not serviceable.

Answer (score 7):

Near as I can tell from the posted pictures you have [Maillard CXC](http://www.velo-pages.com/main.php?g2_itemId=30124&g2_imageViewsIndex=1) pedals.
My guess is that you have the 500 model that can't be repaired.

["Baldy" has an account](https://panabloga.blogspot.com/2018/03/raleighcarlton-grand-prix-maillard-cxc.html) on his blog of working on the model 500 version, sadly he does not say how he will remove the "swaged-in bearings":

> It turns out the bearings are 'swaged' in at the outer edge and are designed not to be removed. To give the bearings some lubrication I left them soaking in a tub of thick oil for 24 hours and then applied some fresh grease into the rim of the bearing using a small cable-tie end. In future I will remove the swaged-in bearings and replace them with removable, self-serviceable bearings.

It looks like the visible difference between the two models is the shape of the axle cover cap.

If you have the 500 you need new pedals. They are not made to be serviceable.
If you have the 550 - based on the description - you will be able to pop the cap off to get to the nut and cone.

The 500 model
[image]

The 550 model
[image]
The 500 model is not designed to be adjusted/repaired
The 550 model

According to [velobase.com](http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=5c3ff5dc-5a47-4011-98ca-f659eddb0063&Enum=109)

> Maillard 1983 CX pedal catalogue http://www.velo-pages.com/main.php?g2_itemId=30117 gives the following, in French:
>
> - CX 500 Integrated flat back plate, bearings not adjustable. low dome cap. (pictured)
> - CX 550 + adjustable bearings under highdome pop-off steel cap.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very precise. And yes this is indeed the unrepairable model, dam. Ill get some new ones :=)

Comment: @Mint hold up - they're not "designed" to be repaired.  Doesn't mean they can't be improved, but you do need to reset your expectations.  It may require drilling and cutting and tapping, and possibly fabrication of replacement parts.  And you might have to replace the whole pedal anyway.   A third option is to move this platform to a new shaft that can be serviced while retaining much of the look.   All comes down to time/effort/money

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to disassemble the axle to get access to the bearings.  If there's no clear flats, or a 6 or 8 sided nut visible, then you might be looking at a one-time assembly.

Try turning the rosette-end of the shaft visible in the photos, using needle nosed pliers.  I suspect it won't do anything.

---

However as a half-way option, try dropping some solvent in the open end, shake it around to clean out the old lubricant and dump it out to flush out sediments/grit.  Repeat.

Once it has dried, add fresh lubricant, and spin the pedal for a while to help it settle.

Then find some way to seal the end of the pedal - perhaps salvage some kind of end cap from elsewhere, or even just sticking some duct tape over the end to keep the world out.

---

Your other option is to buy replacement pedals.  They look like vintage road cleats - downside of modern ones is might not look "right".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is the bearings are broken, they need to get out so no damage happens to the cups. I thought of trying to block the axle some how and see if i could turn it somehow.

Comment: Cleat is the part that is attached to the shoe. This style of pedals is supposed to be used with toe clips, straps and possibly with a non-locking cleat.

Comment: @ojs Yes nailed-on or screwed-on pedal plates that slot into the rear end of the pedal. To be used together with clips and toe-straps. A nightmare for novices!